# How to use excel after save event to run a power query query then save again

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel Workbook that uses Power Query to populate a table. The query pulls information from multiple external Workbooks as well as a table in a Worksheet within the same Workbook.

The Worksheet in the same Workbook also stores changes to columns that are meant to be manipulated. The Worksheet in the same Workbook is part of a loop. It stores information that is pulled into the main table but also stores the changes made.

To make this work correctly, the Workbook needs to be Saved before the storage query runs. If a Save does not occur before running the query, the query will not contain the changes.

This is accomplished easily when clicking the save button. The following code works well:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Stored").Refresh
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This does not work when the workbook is closed and save is clicked after clicking the document close.

The `BeforeSave` event does not fire because it does not get a chance to. The document closes and when it is reopened it shows it as a crashed file and is listed in the recovery list.

Can anyone help me understand why and how to overcome it.

Comment: No repo - the event fires for me after clicking close then save

Comment: Now that you say that, for me it does not fire because it does not get a chance to. The document closes and when it is reopened it shows it as a crashed file and is listed in the recovery list.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is caused by an Excel crash while closing, it's possible that the Refresh gets messed up when Close is underway.

You could try executing the Refresh before Closing, like this

```
Private Closing As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Closing = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Stored").Refresh
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Closing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Stored").Refresh
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```